# default command-F search folder

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, search

Somehow I have changed this, and I want to change it back.  In Finder, on command-F "Find", I default to my home folder, not the current folder.  (The "This Mac" choice is also there.)  I don't remember how I did this, but I want it back to the default behavior.  Other users on this machine do have the default behavior.  I tried trashing ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist (or whatever it is called).
[MacOS 10.6.8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Finder's Preference panel (Cmd-,). There, under the extended settings, you'll find a dropdown list that allows you to choose between "This Mac", the current folder or the last search range.

<sup>(Note: I checked this for a German Snow Leopard installation, so perhaps my re-translations may be a bit off -- sorry for that!)</sup>

Comment: I tried that before, it didn't work.  But it suggested the problem is in Finder not Spotlight.  So I trashed the Finder prefs.  FIXED!  Of course now I have to re-do the prefs that I want.